# Android XML Schema Validation

Tags: android, xml, validation, xsd

I am trying to validate the XML using a local schema file (xsd) in an application that will be run on android. I followed the instructions on the android developer docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html).

I am able to validate my xml file in java but it raises an IllegalArgument exception (code mentioned below) when run on android.

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
```

Please advice on how to proceed with XML schema validation on android. Are there any schema validation libraries that work on android ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The API is here in Android, but not the implementation ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6362749/715269)).  So the only way is to add the functionality by some external jar, Crimson or Xerces. Not a great problem. Have you looked [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I looked at the javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.class file and I see that there is no implementation. The API is there but the implementation is missing. Is XML schema validation possible in android?

Comment: You are aboslutely correct. So the only way is to add the functionality by some external jar. Not a great problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried Xerces but having problems performing schema validation with it too (similar problems as here[link](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2---Android-with-Xerces)). Have you tried validating with Xerces? I am yet to try Crimson.